# Calling a method of a class which extends Thread, from another class

Tags: java, multithreading

I know this is a bit naive question but I want to understand the basic working principle behind multi-threading in java. Consider the following code and say A is executed in Main thread and it starts execution of another worker thread ,defined in class B. I want to know that can B.func1 called from A and run method of B, be executed in parallel or not?

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B obj = new B();
        obj.start();
        obj.func1();
    }
}

public class B extends Thread {
    public B() {
        //constructor
    }
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            //do somethings
        }
    }
    public void func1() {
        //do someotherthings
    }
}
```

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels shared fields should be properly synchronized, for some cases making them volatile will be sufficient, but for other cases this may involve other synchronization mechanisms

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, IMO, you will only lead the noobs astray by telling them to synchronize _methods_.  The only purpose of synchronization is to protect _data_.  Often we talk about the need to synchronize a method, when what we really mean is we need to synchronize some bit of data that is _exclusively_ accessed by the method.  But more often, the same data can be accessed by more than one method.  The noobs need to learn that `synchronized` doesn't work unless _every_ bit of code that accesses the shared data is `synchronized` on the _same object_.

Comment: @jameslarge: you're right. Comment deleted, and thank you for the clarification/correction.

Comment: Is it possible to determine the order of execution? Class B's run method followed by Class B's funct1 method or the other way around?

Answer (score 7):

There is no magic behind a method call. If you call method from a thread, it is called in exactly the same thread. So since `obj.func1()` is called from `main`, it will be run in the main thread. It doesn't matter which class it belongs to or whether or not it extends `Thread`.

The new thread starts by executing `run`. Everything called from run and so on will be executed in parallel to `main`.

Comment: Just realized that you have corrected the source code in question itself :)

Answer (score 2):

It's important to understand the difference between a *thread* and a `Thread`.

A *thread* is an independent execution of your code.  Often when we talk about how some method or another works we say things like, "It tests the variable `x`, and if `x` is less than zero it calls the `foobar` method..."

Ok, but what is the "it" in that sentence?  *It* is not the method.  Methods don't *do* anything.  A method is just a list of instructions, like the list of chores that somebody left for their housemate to perform.  The list doesn't do the chores, it's the housemate that does the work (or so we might hope).

The "it" is a *thread*.  Threads are entities in the operating system that *execute* methods (i.e., they do the chores).

A `Thread`, on the other hand, is a Java object that your program can use to create and manage new *threads*.  Your program creates a new `Thread` object by doing:

```
thread t = new Thread(...);
```

[Oops!  See what I just did?  It's not *your program*, that does the work, it's your program's *main thread*, or maybe some other thread in your program.  It's an easy thing to forget!]

Anyway, it subsequently creates the new *thread* by calling `t.start();`

---

Once you understand all that, then Sergey Tachenov's answer becomes obvious:  Calling the methods of a `Thread` object really is no different from calling methods of any other kind of object.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues with your code. I have corrected them and added one more statement to print Thread Name in func1().

Working code:

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        B obj = new B();
        obj.start();
        obj.func1();
    }
}

class B extends Thread{
    public B (){
        //constructor
    }
    public void run(){
        while(true){
            //do somethings
        }
    }
    public void func1 (){
        //do someotherthings
        System.out.println("Thread name="+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}
```

output:

```
Thread name=main
```

Since you are directly calling func1() from main method (A.java) , you will get `Thread name = main` in output.

If you add same print statement `run()` method, you will get output as : `Thread name=Thread-0`