# Handler's `handleMessage` returning thread id of main thread instead that of the worker thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-handler, android-looper

I'm trying to get a hang of multi-threading in Android. My aim is to send data from the main thread to a worker thread.

I have a main activity with the following code in its `onCreate`-

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ThreadOne threadOne = new ThreadOne();
        threadOne.start();
        threadOneLooper = threadOne.getLooper();

        Message msg = new Message();
        msg.obj = "message.";

        Log.i("id--(threadOneLooper)", String.valueOf(threadOneLooper.getThread().getId()));
        Log.i("id--(Main)", String.valueOf(getMainLooper().getThread().getId()));

        TestHandler mHandler = new TestHandler(threadOneLooper);
        mHandler.handleMessage(msg);
    }
```

As you can observe, I store a reference of the worker thread's looper in `threadOneLooper` and then log the id of its associated thread.
At the same time I also print the id of the main thread.

Following is the code for my thread -

```
public class ThreadOne extends Thread{

    @Override
    public void run() {

        if (Looper.myLooper() == null)
            Looper.prepare();

        Log.i("ThreadOne", "run()");

        // Just making sure all approaches give the same result
        Log.i("Id--Thread id 1", String.valueOf(getLooper().getThread().getId()));
        Log.i("Id--Thread id 2", String.valueOf(getId()));

        Looper.loop();
    }

     Looper getLooper() {
        if (Looper.myLooper() != null)
            return Looper.myLooper();
        else
            return null;
    }
```

And following is the code of my handler -

```
public class TestHandler extends Handler {

    TestHandler(Looper myLooper) {
        super(myLooper);
    }
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        String txt = (String) msg.obj;
        Log.i("Handler", txt);
        Log.i("Id--(Handler)", String.valueOf(getLooper().getThread().getId()));
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is that I had assumed that the `Log.i("Id--(Handler)", String.valueOf(getLooper().getThread().getId()));` statement would log the thread id of `ThreadOne` since we are passing the thread's looper into the handler. However, the id being logged is of the main thread. Why is that? Is it correct to assume that `handleMessage()` is being executed on the main thread?

Comment: Please go through the Android Looper, Handler and MessageQueue. It will give you the answer
https://blog.mindorks.com/android-core-looper-handler-and-handlerthread-bd54d69fe91a

Comment: The main reason is you created the handler inside main thread that why this handler always catch messages come to main thread

Comment: @Jasurbek But I'm passing the looper of the worker thread into the handler. Should not the handler associate itself with the worker in that case?

Comment: I don't have an answer yet. But I realised my approach was incorrect - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671500/calling-a-method-of-a-class-which-extends-thread-from-another-class

Using your approach is giving me a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the `getLooper()` method of `ThreadOne`. The method returns [myLooper()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper#myLooper()) associated with the thread that called the method.

For returning a *Looper* associated with `ThreadOne` I'd suggest the following implementation of the class:

```
public class ThreadOne extends Thread {
    private Looper mLooper = null;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();
        mLooper = Looper.myLooper();

        Looper.loop();
    }

    Looper getLooper() {
        return mLooper;
    }
}
```

**Note!** The `ThreadOne`'s *Looper* is `null` until it is running. You cannot get non-`null` reference to it earlier. You must [check if the thread is running](https://stackoverflow.com/q/861346/3290339) before calling the `getLooper()` method.

P.S. You might want to reconsider the approach with getting the `ThreadOne`'s *Looper*. Having a *Handler* associated with `ThreadOne` might be enough ([see the example of thread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper)).